# reference issue using vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have 3 columns, with headers `A` `B` & `C` as shown at the picture, and I want to check if the value in column `A` is equal to 10% of column `B`, if yes, I want to set it to be the value for column `C`, if not, I want to get 10% of values in column `B`. I am in `sheet1` and I want to set a VBA button in `sheet2` to run the codes.

Here is the code:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lastrow As Long
    Set ws = Worksheets("sheet1")
    ws.Activate
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(A2=B2*0.1, A2, B2*0.1)"
    lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("C2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("C2:C" & lastrow), Type:=xlFillDefault
End Sub
```

My issues is if I point my mouse at `C2` in `sheet1` and I just run the vba codes, it will work. If I am at `sheet2` and pressing the button, it won't work, it just doesn't show any data. Is there a way to set values to column `C` based on my criteria?

[image: worksheet]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the code working on `sheet1` independently of active sheet is, you need to apply `.Range` method exactly to `Worksheets("sheet1")` object. Try the below code:

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim lastrow As Long

    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        lastrow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If lastrow = 1 Then
            MsgBox "No data"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        .Range("C2:C" & lastrow).Formula = "=IF(A2=B2*0.1, A2, B2*0.1)"
    End With

End Sub
```

Why not to be more straightforward: always set the value to column `C` equal to 10% of column `B`? The result will be the same.

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim lastrow As Long

    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        lastrow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If lastrow = 1 Then
            MsgBox "No data"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        .Range("C2:C" & lastrow).Formula = "=B2*0.1"
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: The OP wants the code to execute on Sheet1.  I would alsi remove the Exit Sub in add an Else clause to the if statement.

Comment: @ThomasInzina Now I see that missed something. Fixed the answer.